# C# Singleton implementation performance

Tags: c#, performance, singleton

I'm in the process of learning C#, after I quit programming since a long time (back in early '90, used to program in C and Assembler), so I'm pretty new to C# and OOP in general.

I stumbled upon this strange behaviour when studying the Singleton pattern and its implementation. I saw that some people use the if (==), while others use the if (!=) to check if the instance has already been created or not. I wondered if there was any significant performance difference between the two (from a logic point of view, they ofc work exactly the same), and after some testing I found out that the != is way faster than the == (between 12% and 22%!), and I can't really understand why.

I know that this implementation is not thread-safe btw, I wrote it just to try and get an answer to my curiosity, so please don't bash me about it. :)

So, anyone has an answer to this? Specifically, I'm interested in why this happens. This is the code I used:

**Test Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SingletonSpeedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool wantToQuit = false;
            while (!wantToQuit)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number of cycles: ");
                UInt64 cycles = Convert.ToUInt64(Console.ReadLine());

                long avg1 = Singleton1.TestSingleton(cycles);
                long avg2 = Singleton2.TestSingleton(cycles);
                float perc = (float) (avg2 - avg1) / avg1 * 100;

                Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of ticks in Singleton with == in if: " + avg1);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of ticks in Singleton with != in if: " + avg2);
                Console.WriteLine("Difference in percentage is " + perc + "%");
                Console.Write("\nDo you want to quit? (y/n): ");

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "y") wantToQuit = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Singleton1 Class with == in if:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SingletonSpeedTest
{
    public sealed class Singleton1
    {
        private static Singleton1 instance = null;

        private Singleton1() { }

        public static Singleton1 Instance()
        {
            if (instance == null) instance = new Singleton1();
            return instance;
        }

        public static long TestSingleton(UInt64 cycles)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (UInt64 i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
            {
                Instance();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return sw.ElapsedTicks;
        }
    }
}
```

**Singleton2 Class with != in if**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SingletonSpeedTest
{
    public sealed class Singleton2
    {
        private static Singleton2 instance = null;

        private Singleton2() { }

        public static Singleton2 Instance()
        {
            if (instance != null) return instance;
            return instance = new Singleton2();
        }

        public static long TestSingleton(UInt64 cycles)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (UInt64 i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
            {
                Instance();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return sw.ElapsedTicks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't bother about micro-optimization

Comment: How extensive was your testing? I have not tested the code myself, but the garbage collector may be impacting your results.

Comment: Switch Singleton2 to run before Singleton1 and you'll see that now Singleton2 probably takes longer.

Comment: @CharlesNRice Sorry, I didn't say it in the original post: already tried switching Singleton2 before Singleton1, same result, Singleton2 is always faster than Singleton1.

Comment: @kailanjian I compiled the code as a Console Application, and tried it on my 3 PCs at home, and even asked some friends to run some tests, we all reported the same result.

Comment: You are right I had the same results, though not as extreme. For me it was around 5-7% difference.

Comment: Putting the case that is most often hit up top avoids a jump instruction and is easier on the CPU.  This is not micro-optimization; it's nano-optimization, and I do in fact go to this level in the most performance critical code in realtime systems, but these are systems where the performance will almost directly translate into my company's bonus checks due to competition.  Don't listen to @EhsanSajjad - 7% is real.

Comment: @hoodaticus 7% of an operation that takes an hour can be a huge deal.  7% of an operation that takes .00000001 seconds matters *very, very* rarely.  Most programmers aren't going to write a program for which an optimization like this matters in their entire lives, and those that do are only going to be doing so in very rare circumstances.

Comment: There's a .NET Singleton template somewhere...  Let me check my libraries.

Comment: When you're counting nanoseconds, literally everything counts.  I am strongly opposed to the cliche' assumption that "don't bother about micro-optimization" is a helpful comment when the questioner has not provided you enough information to determine whether it is important or not.  It comes across as arrogant pabulum because it is.

Comment: Just to make things clear, I asked the question primarily to UNDERSTAND what was happening under the hood. The IL code was very useful in letting me understand that.
I don't see anything wrong in learning more, even if it's not that useful most of the time in real life applications, and I like knowledge. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the program is compiled, you can see that Singleton2 has a few extra instructions, but it branches directly to the end if it sees that the instance exists. This gives it the speed boost you are seeing.

Here is the IL code for the instance methods of the two classes:

Singleton1:

```
.method public hidebysig static class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1 
    Instance() cil managed
{
  // Code size       33 (0x21)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool V_0,
           [1] class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1 V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1 SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1::'instance'
  IL_0006:  ldnull
  IL_0007:  ceq
  IL_0009:  stloc.0
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  brfalse.s  IL_0017
  IL_000d:  newobj     instance void SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1::.ctor()
  IL_0012:  stsfld     class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1 SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1::'instance'
  IL_0017:  ldsfld     class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1 SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton1::'instance'
  IL_001c:  stloc.1
  IL_001d:  br.s       IL_001f
  IL_001f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0020:  ret
} // end of method Singleton1::Instance
```

Singleton2:

```
.method public hidebysig static class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2 
    Instance() cil managed
{
  // Code size       37 (0x25)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool V_0,
       [1] class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2 V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2 SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2::'instance'
  IL_0006:  ldnull
  IL_0007:  cgt.un
  IL_0009:  stloc.0
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  brfalse.s  IL_0015
  IL_000d:  ldsfld     class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2 SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2::'instance'
  IL_0012:  stloc.1
  IL_0013:  br.s       IL_0023
  IL_0015:  newobj     instance void SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2::.ctor()
  IL_001a:  dup
  IL_001b:  stsfld     class SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2 SingletonSpeedTest.Singleton2::'instance'
  IL_0020:  stloc.1
  IL_0021:  br.s       IL_0023
  IL_0023:  ldloc.1
  IL_0024:  ret
} // end of method Singleton2::Instance
```

This was generated with the MS ILDASM tool (interpreted language disassembler).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to google up all the IL instructions to better understand the code, but at a first glance basically in the IL code the first one uses, when the singleton is not null, there's a branch more than the second one (the one at 000b), so I guess (iirc from my assembly days) that in this case there's a performance hit due to the additional load of a new address in the IP register.

Answer (score 1):

This is my Singleton base class I've used for years:

```
public class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
{
    static SingletonBase()
    {
    }

    public static readonly T Instance = 
        typeof(T).InvokeMember(typeof(T).Name, 
                                BindingFlags.CreateInstance | 
                                BindingFlags.Instance |
                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                                null, null, null) as T;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `new()` constraint there?

Comment: @hoodaticus no, we really don't want the class to have a public parameterless constructor.  This is why it uses Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1 you are doing a goto almost every time to skip past the call to operator new.  In case 2 you only do a goto if you have not initialized the variable, i.e., once.  Simply put - case 2 does less work per call.

Comment: I suspected that it could be how the compiler writes the assembly code, and that the JMP used in the == if could impact the performance.
I guess that this impact is noticeable only when dealing with objects and not with primitives though. Am I wrong?

Comment: A reference IS a primitive @Galandil.

Comment: Ooops you're right, I always tend to forget it and consider basic primitive types only the int, float, bool, etc. :>